# Why my values from sklearn confusion_matrix and plot_confusion_matrix are not equal?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working on a K-nearest neighbor classifier and I want to add a confusion matrix to my report.

```
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
neigh.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pre = neigh.predict(X_train)
yhat = neigh.predict(X_test)
```

I try using confusion_matrix function like this

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat)
```

It works fine but I want more photogenic representation so I switched to plot_confusion_matrix

```
matrix = plot_confusion_matrix(neigh, X_test, yhat)
```

Turns out that the values that came from these functions [are not equal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogdZJ.jpg) What happened here? What's the right result? And what shoud I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are passing `y_test` data set with `y_hat` data set and in `plot_confusion_matrix` you are passing `X_test` and `y_hat`. You need to make sure which array of data you want to pass into the each method.

Take a look at the scikit-learn documentation ([sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html))

Answer (score 0):

`y_hat` is the prediction on `X_test` and you are passing it as the true labels to `plot_confusion_matrix instead of passing` y_test`. All you need to do is changing that line:

```
matrix = plot_confusion_matrix(neigh, X_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

*This works for me, and always gives me consistent results*

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, preds, labels=finalized_pipeline.classes_)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,display_labels= finalized_pipeline.classes_)
disp.plot();
```